# Need a Regular expression for username validation using php

Tags: php, regex

I need the best regular expression for username validation using core php. I got many expression but none of them is worked.

- Must start with letter
- 6-32 character
- must be at least 1 number

The main problem is that username is exists without inserting number . I need to work the username with above mention expression.

Comment: Can you give us some code or past attempts?

Comment: What are your expressions currently? What failed?

Comment: I am currently using this expression for username validation /^[A-Za-z]{1}[A-Za-z0-9]{5-31}$/ but its not working currently username exists on databse without number so i need to fix that

Comment: That regex allows the string to start with a letter and then 5-31 characters that are a-z or a number. You should add the to your question. Also putting `ASAP` doesn't help your question in anyway..

Comment: The regex that i have mention is not correctly working username is inserting  on database without consisting any number so i need to work with my project so i need it ASAP !!

Comment: Your `ASAP` with lots of `!!!` is getting you a good few downvotes. Maybe it would be a good idea _not_ to add that to questions?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a positive look-aheads with `preg_match`

```
preg_match("/^(?=[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).{6,32}/", $username);
```

`(?=.*\d)` will verify there's at least one digit.

`(?=.*[A-Z])` verifies there's at least one upper case character.

`(?=.*[a-z])` verifies there's at least one lower case character.

`.{6,32}` verifies the string is between 6-32 characters long.

Comment: OP modified question after your answer. `Must Start with letter`, `6-32 character`, don't know about the downvote though..

Comment: Thanks for the heads up :). Updated the answer for the edited question.

Comment: Thanks Martin its really goona worked on my form validation. Thanks for your support. Sorry that i can't vote for your answer becuz of less reputation on my profile so

Answer (score 0):

How about this one

```
$\S*(?=\S{6,})(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*[\d])\S*$
```

You may try it out as per below example

```
$username='Abc123';
$opt=array();

if (preg_match_all('$\S*(?=\S{6,})(?=\S*[a-z])(?=\S*[A-Z])(?=\S*[\d])\S*$',$username ,$opt))
{
   echo 'true';             
}   
else 
{
   echo 'fail';
}
```

Comment: This is untested, right? `$` is the end of the string.. Why the `\s`s, OP doesn't want username to have spaces..